# CodeMagic Post Script iOS Crashlytics Flutter fails with No such file or directory

Tags: ios, flutter, crashlytics, codemagic

I have a `Post-Publish` script in my **CodeMagic** flow to upload the `dsym`-file for **Crashlytics**.

But it fails with:

> Find build artifacts
> find: /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive: No such file or directory
> No debug symbols were found, skip publishing to Firebase Crashlytics

I copied the script from [here](https://docs.codemagic.io/knowledge-firebase/firebase-crashlytics-dsym-uploading/) and it is working fine on other Applications.

What am I missing here? How can I fix this?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

probably your app is not in the project root or generates other Xcarchive name. In this case you need to adjust `$CM_BUILD_DIR/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive` path in the script you use.

You can use remote access to the build machine to find the correct path. Read about remote access [here](https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "use remote access to the build machine to find the correct path"? :D sorry, new on this stuff..

Comment: updated answer with a link